# Speeding ticket cost

Tags: data-request, cars

I am looking for a data set listing the cost of speeding tickets, with as many following fields as possible:

- Area (e.g., country)
- Speed over the limit
- Cost of ticket
- Indirect costs (E.g., insurance raise, or driving school lessons)
- Consequences other than financial ones (e.g., jail time, or loss of drive license points)
- Year (since data may change over the years)

Comment: Here is the official [Swiss data](https://www.ch.ch/en/driving-over-speed-limit/)

Answer (score 3):

Montgomery County, Maryland has this on data.gov, here's the headers:

```
  
Date Of Stop,Time Of Stop,Agency,SubAgency,Description,Location,
Latitude,Longitude,Accident,Belts,Personal Injury,
Property Damage,Fatal,Commercial License,HAZMAT,Commercial Vehicle,Alcohol,
Work Zone,State,VehicleType,Year,Make,Model,Color,
Violation Type,Charge,Article,Contributed To Accident,
Race,Gender,Driver City,Driver State,DL State,Arrest Type,Geolocation
```

https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/traffic-violations-56dda

New Jersey has traffic violations data, but you're going to have to pull out the speeding citations, also I didn't cross-reference required headers:
https://opendata.socrata.com/Government/New-Jersey-Traffic-Violations/2667-zax6

Los Angeles' Open Data portal offers similar sets that you can pick through:
https://data.lacity.org/browse?q=traffic